Problem with two way data binding with ObservableCollection
I have three pages in the project with two ViewModels, and two models. The first page populates open orders into a ListView without a problem. When a ListView item is tapped (Orders_ItemTapped) in the first page code behind it supposed populate the order items into a ListView of the second page. But the second page shows blank ListView.
I don't have any errors while debugging and the tapped event is calling all methods but nothing seems to work. After further researching the problem seems to come from the two way data binding issues or the way I'm using the ViewModel or instantiating the ViewModel and Methods in the Tapped event of the first page.
To further test, I hard coded the GetOrderItemsById() to populate the list<> in the constructor of the second ViewModel and it properly displays all the order items to the second page.
I'm not familiar with the Dependency Injection try to it but I want to learn what I'm doing wrong with my current method. I'm guessing my problem has something to do with the way I'm using the ObservableCollection property/constructor in the ViewModel or instantiating ViewModel in the tapped event.
Page 1 "OpenOrdersPage" Code Behind
using ApexHQ_Mobile.Models;
using ApexHQ_Mobile.ViewModels;
namespace ApexHQ_Mobile.Pages;

public partial class OpenOrdersPage : ContentPage
{
    private OpenWOrdersVM vm;
    public OpenOrdersPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new OpenWOrdersVM();
        this.BindingContext = this.vm;
    }

    private  void Orders_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var order = (WarehouseOrder)e.Item;
            var vm = new WOrderItemsVM { OrderId = order.Id };
            vm.GetOrderItems();
            var itemsPage = new WOrderItemsPage();
            itemsPage.BindingContext = vm;
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(itemsPage ));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
            throw;
        }
    }
}

Page 2 "WOrderItemsPage" code behind
using ApexHQ_Mobile.ViewModels;
namespace ApexHQ_Mobile.Pages;

public partial class WOrderItemsPage : ContentPage
{
    private WOrderItemsVM vm;
    public WOrderItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new WOrderItemsVM();
        this.BindingContext = this.vm;
    }

    private void Order_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Future use to populate OrderItemDetail Page
    }
}

ViewModel 1 "OpenWOrdersVM"
using ApexHQ_Mobile.Models;
using ApexHQ_Mobile.Services.Database;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ApexHQ_Mobile.ViewModels;

internal partial class OpenWOrdersVM : ObservableObject
{
    public WarehouseOrder order {  get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<WarehouseOrder> orders = new();

    //Initialize View Model in the constructor
    public OpenWOrdersVM()
    {
        orders.Clear();
        orders = new ObservableCollection<WarehouseOrder>(WarehoueOrderService.GetWarehoueOrders());
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void GoBack()
    {
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void ShowOrderList()
    {
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }
}

ViewModel 2 "WOrderItemsVM"
using ApexHQ_Mobile.Models;
using ApexHQ_Mobile.Services.Database;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace ApexHQ_Mobile.ViewModels
{
    public partial class WOrderItemsVM: ObservableObject
    {
        private WOItem item { get; set; }

        private ObservableCollection<WOItem> items = new();

        private long orderId;
        public long OrderId
        {
            get => orderId;

            set => SetProperty(ref orderId, value);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<WOItem> Items
        {
            get => items;
            set => SetProperty(ref items, value);
        }

        //public ObservableCollection<WOItem> Items { get { return items; } }

        public void GetOrderItems()
        {
            try
            {
                Items.Clear();
                var items = new ObservableCollection<WOItem>(WarehoueOrderService.GetOrderItemsById(orderId));
                if (items != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

            
        }

        //public WOrderItemsVM()
        //{
        //    GetOrderItems();
        //}
    }
}

Page Route AppShell.xaml.cs
using ApexHQ_Mobile.Pages;
namespace ApexHQ_Mobile;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Page Route
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(OpenOrdersPage), typeof(OpenOrdersPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof("itemsPage"), typeof(WOrderItemsPage));
    }
}


Could you please post the code of  OpenOrdersPage.xaml and WOrderItemsPage.xaml ?

In Orders_ItemTapped you are initializing a new WOrderItemsPage and setting the bindigcontext of the page to your first page vm??????.
  var itemsPage = new WOrderItemsPage();
  itemsPage.BindingContext = vm;

But you never used the newly created page object.
You're just navigating to another new instance of the page by using.
Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(WOrderItemsPage));

Above navigation call will create new instance of the page and then new instance of the WOrderItemsVm as defined in the constructor.
If Passing the Items from first page to second page is you goal then,
while initializing the WOrderItemsPage object, pass it through it's constructor and then to VM. Like below
 var itemsPage = new WOrderItemsPage(Items);
 await Shell.Current.PushAsync(itemsPage);

and from page you can pass it to vm
    public WOrderItemsPage(ObservableCollection<WOItem> items)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new WOrderItemsVM(items);
        this.BindingContext = this.vm;
    }

Assgn the itemsource of you collectionview in the constructor of vm
        public WOrderItemsVM(ObservableCollection<WOItem> items)
        {
            Items = items;
        }

Better to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in vm to notify the view know more
      private ObservableCollection<WOItem> items;
      public ObservableCollection<WOItem> Items
        {
            get => items;
            set 
            {
              items = value;
              PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEeventArgs(nameof(Items));
            }
        }


Thank you for your reply. Not using the non-binding page, WOrderItemsPage, was from my mistake while testing. I did use the initialized itemsPage to navigate to the new page. My mistake maybe no passing the ObservableCollection Items. I will make the changes and followup later today. Thank you once again for your help.

I change the Orders_ItemTapped event, I pass the "order" into the VM constructor to populate the data. I then create an instance of the second page "WOrderItemsPage" binding it to the VM and navigate to the page using Shell. However, it does not work, the ListView shows blank list. I then change the navigation to Navigation.PushAsync and works. I don't know what the difference is but the Shell navigation will not work and the Navigation.PushAsync works. Can someone please explain the difference and how I can make it work with the Shell navigation.

private void Orders_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
try
{
var order = (WarehouseOrder)e.Item;
var vm = new WOrderItemsVM(order);
var itemsPage = new WOrderItemsPage();
itemsPage.BindingContext = vm;
//Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(itemsPage));
Navigation.PushAsync(itemsPage);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
throw;
}
}

@MikeYim How are you navigating to OpenOrdersPage  in first place?

Initially, I used Shell Navigation. I've fixed my problem using Shell Navigation. I will post shortly.

Thank you to those taking the time to help me. I've solved my problem . In my Tapped event, I pass the "order id" to the 2nd page using [QueryProperty] and bind the View Model. Please see code.
Page 1 ListView Event code
private async void Orders_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e{
try
{
    var order = (WarehouseOrder)e.Item;
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(WOrderItemsPage)}?Id={order.Id}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
    throw;
}}

Page 2 Code Behind
[QueryProperty(nameof(OrderID), "Id")]

public partial class WOrderItemsPage : ContentPage{
private WOrderItemsVM vm;
private long orderid;

public WOrderItemsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public long OrderID
{
    set 
    {
        orderid = value;
        vm = new WOrderItemsVM(orderid);
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
private void Order_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    // Future use to populate OrderItemDetail Page
}}

